# Routing to a different URLs based on post type

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

What would be the best way to set up my routes so different types of posts have different URLs?

For example, regular posts are `/posts/slug` while featured posts are `/featured/slug`

Both link to the same controller and action `/posts/view/slug`.

I experimented with different ways of doing this but with little success. Currently my link params look something like the following:

```
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'featured' ,$post['Post']['slug'])
```

Edit: I could create an action for each different type and use setAction to use the view action instead. Although is there a better way to do this?

```
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'featured', $post['Post']['slug'])

function featured($slug) {
    $this->setAction('view', $slug);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can also do this by adding follow line in your /app/config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/featured/*',array('action' => 'view'));
```

See [route setting in cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
// app/config/routes.php
Router::connect('/featured/:slug', array(
  'controller' => 'posts',
  'action' => 'view',
  'type' => 'featured'
));
Router::connect('/posts/:slug', array(
  'controller' => 'posts',
  'action' => 'view',
  'type' => 'normal'
));

// one of your views
echo $html->link('Featured post title', array(
  'controller' => 'posts',
  'action' => 'view',
  'type' => 'featured',
  'slug' => $post['Post']['slug']
));
or
echo $html->link('Normal post title', array(
  'controller' => 'posts',
  'action' => 'view',
  'type' => 'normal',
  'slug' => $post['Post']['slug']
));
```